# Working with multiple wpf windows using c#

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm sorry to post this question because there's a lot of relative subjects with this one but unfortunately none of them couldn't helped me !! 
so I have an application that contains two wpf windows (MainWindow() and Window1()), what i exactly want to achieve is to control the window1 properties from the MainWindow()..
for example i want to clear a listbox items from window1 every time i click on Button1 from the MainWindow !! I also want to have a full access to the methods, fields and properties that exits in the MainWindow from window1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is to add public properties/method that allows access to your `Window1` class from `MainWindow`.

For instance, if you want to clear a list in `Window1` from `MainWindow`, add the following method to `Window1`:

```
public void ClearList()
{
    // Clear your list here
}
```

Of course you'll need your `MainWindow` to know about `Window1`, but as the name suggests, I assume `MainWindow` is the main window so it creates the `Window1` instance.

So you should have a reference to `Window1` in `MainWindow`. In `MainWindow`, just call:

```
this.myWindow1.ClearList();
```

Comment: so like that i don't have to create a reference of Window1 in the MainWindow like windwo1 wind = new window1() ?

Comment: You do have to. How would you show the Window if you don't? First create your instance, then call a method of your instance.

Comment: thanks I'll do that when i need to, but the ClearList() method is not working with me.. when i implement the ClearList() in window1 and when i try to call it in the main window like Window1.ClearList(); it fails !!

Comment: @Destro009 Yes, because you are calling the method to the class itself, not to an instance of the class.

Comment: but it's okey when i use this !! like, this.window1.ClearList() i hope it works fine !!

Answer (score 1):

Where is the problem ? I dont see any question.

Maybe you want to start by saving a ref of Window1 in MainWindow.

```
Window1 window1 = new Window1();
window1.show();
```

From there do what you need done :

```
window1.foo();
window1.bar();
window1.foobar = "Title";
```

Edit : some clarification, because OP seems to be a beginner :

```
public class MainWindow
{

    private Window1 window1;

    public void CreateWindow()
    {
         window1 = new Window1();
         window1.show();
    }

    private void DoStuffWithWindow1()
    {
         window1.foo();
         window1.bar();
         window1.foobar = "Title";
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i've already done that and get the StackOverFlowException !!
An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in *****.exe

Comment: Hum, you must have some recursive call somewhere. Please post code. Are you using any events ?

Comment: no, the exception is about Window1 window1 = new Window1(); ps: i declare the window1 as global variable !!

Comment: Global ? As in class you mean ? When are you initializing window1 ? In the ctor of mainWindow ?

Comment: yes in the public partial class, but i don't understand why every time i run the app a new instance of window1 runs also !!